# Pass value from Typescript to HTML. Error; [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I try to pass array values from a .ts file to a html file in a Angular Project.

The HTML file is:

```
<body>
    <section id="login" class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-items-center">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Firmware</label>
                <input #firmware class="form-control" type="text" value= {{firmware}} readonly>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Bootloader</label>
                <input #bootloader class="form-control" type="text" value= {{bootloader}} readonly>   
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

and the .ts file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dual',
  templateUrl: './dual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dual.component.scss']
})
export class DualComponent implements OnInit {

  title = "";

  constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {


var resultArray:number[] = [235,23] 

        var firmware = resultArray[0];
        var bootloader = resultArray[1];
        console.log("firmware",firmware);
        console.log("bootloader",bootloader);
        
  
  }
}
```

If i show the values via console.log they are shown right but if i try to show them in the HTML file the value in the textbox is "[object HTMLInputElement]"

Note: Im new in Angular and try to learn :)

Any tips?

Thank you!

**Solution**:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Firmware</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value= {{firmware}} readonly>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Bootloader</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value= {{bootloader}} readonly>   
            </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
    var resultArray:number[] = [235,23]
    this.firmware = resultArray[0].toString();
    this.bootloader = resultArray[1].toString();
    console.log("firmware",this.firmware);
    console.log("bootloader",this.bootloader);
```

Comment: firmware and bootloader are local method variables not available to the html.  You need to create (public) class variables for the html to bind to.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my old answer, because I totally missed what was wrong. When you do this:

```
<input #firmware class="form-control" type="text" value= {{firmware}} readonly>
```

The `#firmware` creates a new local variable named `firmware`, which is equal to the HTML element it's contained in. It's that new local variable that is being displayed inside the curly braces, *not* the variable `firmware` which is defined in your `DualComponent` class.

Make sure you don't duplicate variable names like this, and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was the problem. I edit my question with the complete solution